# MVC 4: building composite viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I need to build a composite viewmodel out of three nested or cascading classes: Sport>Tournament>TournamentEvent

```
public class Sport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SportName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tournament> Tournaments { get; set; }
}

public class Tournament
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TournamentName { get; set; }
    public int SportId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TournamentEvent> TournamentEvents { get; set; }
}

public class TournamentEvent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public int TournamentId { get; set; }
}
```

As you can gather, each sport contains a collection of tournaments and each tournament contains a collection of events. I need to construct an unordered list, like so:

```
    <li> Soccer
        <li>English Premier League
            <li>Chelsea v Arsenal</li>
        </li>
    </li>
```

I need to build a composite viewmodel, using linq, to pass to my view, but I just can't figure it out. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just need a parent vie model that contains a list of Sport?

```
public class Sport
{
    public List<Sport> Sports { get; set; }
}
```

You can iterate through the collections using razor.

Can you clarify where you think linq comes into it? I might have got the wrong end of the stick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that works, tom. I need access to the Tournament and TournamentEvent classes and I need to load them into my object, which is where linq comes in. In the SportsController:

```
public partial class SportsController : Controller
{
    private MyDb db = new MyDb();

public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
      var menuObject = from s in db.Sports
                         select s;

      return View(menuObject);
     }
}
```

Comment: I can load the Sport class into the View, but how do I load the Tournament and TournamentEvent classes?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class call it SportTournamentEventViewModel.cs

using "LibraryName".Models;

```
public class SportTournamentEventViewModel
{
    public List<Sport> Sports {get;set;}
    public List<Tournament> Tournaments {get;set;}
    public List<TournamentEvent> Events {get;set;}
}
```

in your action

```
private NameOfEntities db = new NameOfEntities();

public ActionResult "ActionResultName"()
{
    db.Configuration.LazyLoading = false;

    var sportList = db.Sport.ToList();
    var tournamentList = db.Tournament.ToList();
    var eventList = db.TournamentEvents.ToList();

    var viewModel = new SportTournamentViewModel
    {
        Sports = sportList,
        Tournaments = tournamentList,
        Events = eventList,
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```